# How to get column values from multiple tables in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

How can I get a second table's column value on the behalf of 1st table's column specific id, like in this code it is getting the values from the same table but i want to change it to get values from other table on the behalf of User table's column ID.

```
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    $ref_id = $user->referrer_id;
    $ref_user = User::find($ref_id);
    $new_Balance = $ref_user['balance']  = $ref_user['balance'] + 
    $comission->update_commision_sponsor;
    $ref_user->save();
```

I want it to be like this:

```
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    $ref_id = $user->referrer_id;
    $ref_user = User::find($ref_id); (here I want to assign second table where the referrer_id column dose not exist.)
    $new_Balance = $ref_user['balance (here I want second table's column "earning")']  = $ref_user['balance(here I want second table's column "earning")'] + $comission->update_commision_sponsor;
    $ref_user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

An if condition could help

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id());
$ref_id = $user->referrer_id;

if($ref_id == null){
    $anotherTable = AnohterTable::find($id);
    $ref_id == $anotherTable->another_column;
}

$ref_user = User::find($ref_id); (here I want to assign second table where the referrer_id column dose not exist.)
$new_Balance = $ref_user['balance (here I want second table's column "earning")']  = $ref_user['balance(here I want second table's column "earning")'] + $comission->update_commision_sponsor;
$ref_user->save();
```

Comment: I said that second table dose not have the referrer id column

Comment: @Nomi Write the column name which has the id. Replace the `another_column` with that name.